# MS Access Combobox's value doesn't exist in table/query

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I have some `ComboBox`that are configured in `table/query` mode, that means that they get the list of items from a table in the database of Access.
Normally, this `ComboBox` -called `Editar_Codigo` and `Editar_Nombre`- only use the items from the list, but sometimes I want to wrote new items that still doesn't exist in the table (because then I'll press the "add record to table" button).
But there I get the problem, Access spawn a PopUp saying that the values in both `ComboBox` doesn't exist in the table, and I can't close that PopUp until I delete the wrote value in both `ComboBox`.

I found that exist an expresion that is activated when a `ComboBox` get a value that doesn't exist.

```
Private Sub ComboBox_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
End Sub
```

But even using that, this happened:

1. First, I wrote the "wrong" value.
2. Second, the `ComboBox_NotInList` (in my case `Editar_Codigo_NotInList` and `Editar_Nombre_NotInList`) is executed. (I check it open an `MsgBox`).
3. Finally, the Access PopUp is open.

I want to delete the third item of the above "chain event". How can I do that?

**Edit:**

[image]

The idea is to write the code of the product in the `Editar_Codigo` ComboBox, the name in `Editar_Name` and the price and stock in the next two TextBoxs. And finally, press the button called "Añadir", which will add the record to the table called "Lista de Stock".
But the problem is that I can't write "inexistent values" in the ComboBoxes (values that doesn't exist in the table). So I want to be able to "ignore" the PopUp, How can I make Access to not raise a PopUp?

Comment: "where is your add record to the table button"? in your notInList event, after inserting new value, you must return "Response = acDataErrAdded" in order to accept the new value.

Comment: Review http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut20.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I think What you can do is . First of all make that combo to see only one column Alpha, beta ,Gamma. Now whenever user selects the Beta than set property of combo box i.e.  [image: after update]and write code to fetch corresponding value from table. 
Example. Suppose name of combobox is combo1.

```
colomnInvisibleValue = dlookup("colomnName","TableName","VisibleColomnName= '"  & me.combo1.value & "' ")
```

Variable colomnInvisibleValue will contain value (2) according to your last comment.!

Comment: Thanks, I've already know about this solution, but I was trying to avoid it because I wasn't sure why it didn't work for me, it seems that I forget use `"'"`!

Answer (score 1):

set limit to list property of combo box under data tab to no .[image: limit to list property of combo box under data tab]

Comment: Your answer only seem to work with ComboBoxes without invisible dependecy rows. But if I have them, I have to make them visibles, and then the value of the Combobox change to the row that was invisible before instead to another row.

Comment: I didn't get your doubt.!

Comment: I have a ComboBox with two rows -one invisible (row "A") and another not (row "B")- users can only see the row "B", and whent they choose an item from the list, the value of the ComboBox is showed like the pressed item of the row "B" -but inside the code the value is like the row "A" item-. With that ComboBox you answers doesn't work. I had to make visible the  row "A" but now the value showed to users is the row "A" and I want to show the values from the row "B". Sorry for my english...

Comment: You meant to say you have two columns in comboBox ?

Comment: Yes, but one is invicible.

Comment: Still I didn't understand what you want to say. You want to show user the value of B column when user selects value from colomn A ? You only want user to see values of column A ? Is it right ?

Comment: User can only see B column, but inside the code, the selected value is from the column A, e.g: CombBox items -in brackets the invisible row-: ["(1); Alpha", "(2); Betha", "(3); Gamma"]. Users only see: ["Alpha", "Betha", "Gamma"] as the items of the list, and if they choose the "Betha" item, they see the "Betha" item, but, iniside the code the value is "(2)". That is how I am using ComboBoxes, the problem is that with your answer, I have to make the invisible row (in brackets) visible and when someone choose "Beta", they see, "(2)" instead of "Beta".